# Push another View in UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How to push a view using a button in a navigation controller?
I tried to follow this example:
http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/

This is exactly what I need, I have an `UITabBarController` with 4 tabs and one of them is an `UINavigationController`. I want to push that view containing the navigation controller from the first view- which is a simple `UIView`.  It doesn't work, I tried also with a programmatically created button and nothing happens. Any pointers?

Here's the code I have

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)pushViewController:(id)sender;

@end

---

#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "NewViewController.h"

@implementation HomeViewController

-(IBAction)pushViewController:(id)sender {
        NewViewController *controller = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release], controller = nil;
}
```

Here is also the screenshot with the connections 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/847/screenshot20110719at620.png/

I've tried what you guys suggested and still nothing, the buttons( whether they are created in `Interface Builder` or programmatically ) act like they're not linked to any method.

Comment: Try posting your code here so we can see what may be going wrong.

Comment: Have you followed each step of the tutorial well? "It doesn't work" is too abstract to understand your problem. Please post some code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this where you want to create the button: (e.g. the Root VC's `-viewDidLoad`)

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 40.0);
[button setTitle:@"Press" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[viewController.view addSubview:button];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(didPressButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And implement this method:

```
- (void)didPressButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIViewController *viewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use storyboard, create a segue manually

On storyboard:

- click on the view
- then on the right sidebar top menu select the "Show the connections inspector"
- in the "Triggered Segues", click and drag the "manual" trigger to the view you want to push
- chose "push" in the pop menu that will appear

it will create a segue, now select the segue and give it a identifier

Now you can use the code:

```
-(IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self ];
}
```

now you can wire the action to your button

Answer (score 1):

To push a view to the navigation controller just do:

```
YourController *childController = [[YourController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourControllerView" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
[childController release];
```

Now if you want it to happen when pressing a button, add a button to your nib file and connect it to a `IBAction` method on Touch Up Inside event.