# how can i move one screen to another dynamically in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating 5 buttons dynamically in my project.
Now I want code for each of the dynamic buttons to move to the next screen when I click a button.
If you have sample example same like my requirement then please post here.

I know its very easy for drag and drop control to connect next form but I want to do that dynamically.
Code I have so far:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    [
        aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever:)    
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside
    ];
    [scrollView addSubview:aButton];
    yCoord += buttonHeight + buffer;
}
```

Comment: its required segus to connect another screen ???

Comment: what do you mean with "to another screen" exactly?

Comment: means when i cclick a button its move to other screen like (tableview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can push a new UIViewController programmatically

> Refer to this answer: [Push another View in UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749271/push-another-view-in-uinavigationcontroller)
>
> See this answer for using Nibs: [Navigation Controller Push View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742745/navigation-controller-push-view-controller)

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks now please help me how i can set autolayout for multiple dynamic buttons .in same program code

Comment: I think you should accept this answer to your question if it applies and create another question concerning your autolayout problem.