# iOS - Lock a specific UIViewController to a specific orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

My application supports every 4 orientation, I have a `UIViewController` which is in `LandscapeRight`.
I am using `UINavigationController` to push that `UIViewController`, i want that `UIViewController` to be only in `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` but when I rotate the phone, it switches back to other Orientation.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just remove those shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation.

and add this to the viewcontroller you want to display landscape only.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]
                                forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

actually, this is from a similar question with solution here.
[How to force view controller orientation in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a sub class of `UIViewController`. And apply interface orientation related changes in this sub class. Extend your view controller in which you want to lock orientation with the sub class. I'll provide an example of this.

I have create class which only shows landscape orientation for view controller.

`LandscapeViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` in which you have to deal with orientations.

**LandscapeViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LandscapeViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**LandscapeViewController.m:**

```
#import "LandscapeViewController.h"

@interface LandscapeViewController ()

@end

@implementation LandscapeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}

@end
```

**Extend your view controller using above subclass.**

For example:

```
#import "LandscapeViewController.h"

@interface SampleViewController : LandscapeViewController

@end
```