# Objective-C change device orientation for only one UiViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, device-orientation

I want to change device orientation for only one UiViewController. My first UiViewController's name is VideoLaunch. I want Landscape orientation in this UiViewController firstly. When I pass another uiviewcontroller I change a static value which name is "is" to different from nil. When i run in debug mode i see

> else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait

this line runs. But orientation doesn't change.

AppDelegate.m

```
 - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {   
    if([VideoLaunch is] == nil)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

    else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
 }
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009979/ios-lock-a-specific-uiviewcontroller-to-a-specific-orientation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the following method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutoRotate
```

return YES for the one where you want allow rotation.

Then, also override supportedDeviceOrientations and specify what you want in there. For example:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

and make sure that you allowed orientations correctly in your target's General settings.

Comment: after Xcode 7 use `(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations`