# iOS: specific Landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My app has Portrait mode only, as follow image:
[Device Orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jalEL.png)

But it needs to support Landscape mode in customized UIViewController. I have override follow functions:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return NO;
    }

    - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }

    - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
    }
```

It worked in most cases, but somehow it would acted like follow image:
[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIk1D.png)

There seems to have a conflict between the device orientation and MyViewController orientation.

PS: My device is iPhone 6s Plus, system is iOS 10.0, this problem also exist in iPhone 6s.

Comment: can i suggest you alternative of achieve this ?

Comment: yes, plz, i'd like to know, thx

Comment: check my answer . it was working fine in my projects .

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

AppDelegate.h

```
@property () BOOL restrictRotation;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if(self.restrictRotation)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
else
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; // you can change orientation for specific type . for ex landscape left
}
```

ViewController

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
}
```

viewDidLoad

```
[self restrictRotation:YES]; or NO
```

you need to write this line in every viewcontroller where you need to modify

for more : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25952571/3901620

Comment: My project is designed to used by other developers as static library, so modify AppDelegate may not suitable. Thx all the same.

Comment: My code is worked well in most cases, but the MyViewController has not spin fortuitous. And I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering for `ViewController` specific orientation then please refer below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27010196/6325474

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in AppDelegate .This is only possible solution which will work 
Swift code

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> 
UIInterfaceOrientationMask  {

        let vc = self.window?.currentViewController()
        if vc?.isKind(of: YourDesiredVCToChangeOrientation.self) == true {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape;
        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all ;
        }

    }
```