# Enable/disable rotation on Salesforce IOS Hybrid app

Tags: ios, hybrid-mobile-app, screen-rotation, salesforce-ios-sdk

Is there any way to control the rotation of an Salesforce IOS Hybrid app. I'm using Salesforce IOS SDK. I want to have some of the screens allow to rotate and some not. I know we can set it the app's general setting but it will apply across the whole app not into each screen.

Comment: this relates to general iOS development. You can set rotation setting in each view controller separately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force view controller orientation in iOS 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8)