# Set Orientation to Portrait with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app where some of the screens should be in portrait mode and some of them in landscape. For example, main menu is portrait and there is a camera button. The camera should be available only in landscape. I am using Storyboard and NavigationController. Where and what should I do to achieve this?

I already tried to include

```
shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {return false or return true}
```

neither worked. I have set the

```
supportedInterfaceOrientation
```

for every viewcontroller I have. Nothing helped. I need a function what I can call to force the screen into landscape/portrait mode.

Comment: Here was already answered [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8)

Comment: neither of those solutions are working for me. :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this line of code in your ViewDidLoad (or wherever you want).

**Swift 1**
             `UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")`

Tested 3 minutes ago in Swift 1.2 Xcode 6.3

**Swift 3** (Thanks to Fa.Shapouri)

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLe‌​ft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

Comment: will apple reject app using it?

Comment: **Swift 3** :         UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")

Comment: @YifeiHe何一非 No, this solution is ok for the app store