# how to set a viewController only landscape in iOS8.0

Tags: ios, landscape

for i want to build a movie controller,and it`s pushed by a navigationController,how can i set it ,also only this vc can be landscape,others should only be portraitUp,please help,thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force view controller orientation in iOS 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help,i have complete my code,for i rebuild a navigitionController;