# lock orientation programmatically in iOS 9

Tags: ios9, device-orientation

As title, I'm wondering if it's possible to lock orientation programmatically in iOS 9 now? This is critical to my app but I can't find a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684922/ios9-alternative-to-uidevice-currentdevice-setvalue-to-force-orientation , it is not possible in iOS 9.

Answer (score 6):

Use supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation used to manage orientation
for example

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: your viewcontroller inside in navegationController or tabbarcontroller?

Comment: inside a navigation controller, which is, inside tabbarcontroller.

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: Helped me to find out what the problem was. The navigation controller was athorizing all masks

Comment: If the viewcontroller is under a navigationController, you need to add a class for the navigationController and put the code above into the navigationController's class.