# iOS9: Alternative to UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(...) to force orientation

Tags: ios, screen-orientation, ios9

It seems to me this does not work anymore in iOS9. It was the de facto way of forcing orientation changes based my SO research. It now freezes my SpriteKit game.

Is it just me, and if not does anyone know of an alternative?

**EDIT**: Portrait and UpsideDown still work. It seems only Landscape modes now cause a freeze

**EDIT 2:** Actually I think you can go Portrait <--> UpsideDown and LandscapeLeft <--> LandscapeRight, but not in between them

Comment: Its not just you. Forcing orientation no longer works for me on iOS 9, too. I use to force the orientation to landscape when in portrait for certain scenarios.

Comment: you need to set in xcode only...

Comment: iOS9.1,dose NOT work too

Answer (score 18):

Adding to Alex's answer: My experience is that Apple only blocks the orientation change for iOS9 iPads that **don't** require fullscreen. So if you tell the app to require fullscreen, the rotation should work:

[image]

However, I have no clue whether it'll solve your SpriteKit freeze since in my experience iOS9 also introduced plenty of SpriteKit bugs.

Comment: Shame that you have to tick this checkbox (which disables slide-over and split screen in iOS 9) just to be able to force a view into a particular orientation. I would ideally like to be able to do both, but forcing orientation is more important than slide-over/spilt screen at the moment, unless you know a way of having both?

Comment: Hero of the day. Thanks! It saved me some time.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. Setting the device orientation is not possible on iOS 9. I think this is because of the new SplitScreen Mode on iPad. Now there can be 2 Applications at once on screen and it would be "unfair" for the one Application to decide which orientation is allowed. Imagine two Apps which force different orientations, what would happen? I think Apple just prohibits it in general even though they could limit to iPad non-fullscreen Applications

Comment: why is it still working in iOS 10 on iPad ? iPad ios 10 still has the same feature SplitScreen Mode

Answer (score 1):

If you have two or more ViewControllers,and you want each of the ViewControllers has different orientation, I think the best way to force the orientation of the VC is to use these code below:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
// let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

It works for me at iOS 9.