# Forcefully device orientation to Portrait not working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, uiinterfaceorientation, ios9.1

I am using this code snippet to forcefully change the device orientation. It is working fine before iOS 9 it is not working with iOS 9.

```c
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Is there any alteration available in iOS 9?

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684922/ios9-alternative-to-uidevice-currentdevice-setvalue-to-force-orientation).