# cannot force app to portrait-only in iOS9

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I need my app to only support portrait orientation. But after upgrading to iOS9, the orientation settings seem to have no effect. I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33567990/3894781) answer and here's my apps settings :

[image: orientation settings]

but still the app goes into landscape. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: well you must uncheck the "Requires full screen" checkbox

Comment: tried that already. not working.

Comment: Please check "Supported interface orientations" in info.plist file, sometimes info.plist not get update as general tab.

Comment: info.plist has all the required items.

Comment: It must show only Portrait mode .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check Info.plist for "Supported interface orientations".
It must show Portrait for your requirement. Sometimes it is not updated as project settings in General Tab. If you find landscape orientation over here then remove it.

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is some sort of bug in iOS9. It completely overlooks the plist file orientation settings. So I had to add this code to each of my UIViewControllers to get portrait orientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
#else
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
#endif
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I found the problem. When I viewed the *source* of my info.plist, this is what I found :

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

No Idea how the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` key came into being. It was not initially displayed when viewing as a *property list*, but started showing in property list after opened as source and saved.

Also there seems to be now way to set this in the *general* tab. Thanks to [SamB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34568312/3894781) and [technerd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34566392/3894781) for putting me on the right path.

PS: I am not sure if this is a bug or the intended behavior, so I welcome any insights on this.