# Fix orientation on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ipad, orientation

My app only requires Portrait and PortraitUpsideDown. In the target's Deployment Info I only checked these two. In Info.plist all four are available. Xcode wouldn't let me build when I deleted Landscapes from the Info-plist, saying I needed to support all four. Now after running the app through TestFligh, it still returns Landscape although unchecked in the Deployment Info. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Check info.plist orientation list's singularity. Happened to me - I had two for some reason, though I never created one manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot force app to portrait-only in iOS9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566240/cannot-force-app-to-portrait-only-in-ios9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "allow" all 4 options in your settings, but then control the orientation yourself.

I'd create a custom UINavigation controller with this inside (Swift):

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return (visibleViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations())!
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return (visibleViewController?.shouldAutorotate())!
    }
}
```

Then, in each of the ViewControllers you want to force into a particular orientation, you include this:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape // Or portrait
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This way you can allow all orientations, but still maintain control over the views themselves. If you want ALL views to be the same (e.g. landscape), you could create a custom base class for all of your view controllers with the second set of code in it, and you wouldn't have to include it in each individual VC.

Comment: @Kidlcarus271: Works perfectly!