# Programmatically change orientation of ViewController without subclassing UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I'm writing a module which include `UIViewController`(and Storyboard) and it can be called by other wrapper program, so I cannot enforce use specific `UINavigationController`'s subclass, but it can be used by `UINavigationController`.
In this case, how can I change orientation of my `ViewController`? Furthermore, only one `UIViewController` should be orientation changed programmatically.
I tried to use `UINavigationControllerDelegate` but it is not called. (I tried set delegate on both `init` and `viewDidLoad`, but not worked neither)
Is there other way to solve this problem without?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does orientation of VC have to do anyting with UINavigationController ?

Comment: In my understanding... if I change orientation of VC on NavigationController, I should subclass NavigationController, and override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate`

Answer (score 1):

Set this in `viewDidAppear` method of ViewController:

For Landscape:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

OR

For Portrait:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Comment: No luck. In fact, I also need switch button for orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't matter of `UINavigationController`. `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` weren't called since iOS 9 (iPad) blocked them. I could solve this problem checking **Requires full screen** on (Target Settings) - General - Deployment Info.

This is what I found (detail). https://stackoverflow.com/a/33567990/1010443