# How to detect the device orientation changed event on iPad iOS 9+ when the lock is set outside?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios9

on iPad ios 9+, with objective-c : 
- lock the orientation outside of your app
- in code: how to detect when the device changes the orientation?

I have tried all possibilities:

1) try to catch **UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification** event:

```
- (void)subscribeOrientationChangeEvent {

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
}

- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note {

     NSLog("Device rotated");
}
```

2) override **viewWillTransitionToSize** method

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    NSLog("Device rotated");
}
```

3) use KVO to see if the value **orientation** of **[UIDevice currentDevie]**

4) use KVO to see if the value **statusBarOrientation** of **[UIApplication sharedApplication]**

5) set **Require FullScreen** for the setting **StatusBarStyle**

reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684922/ios9-alternative-to-uidevice-currentdevice-setvalue-to-force-orientation)

apply this setting and combine with all above attempts, but all failed.

### 6) using Accelerometer (CMMotionManager)

Any advice? thanks a lot

Comment: Try with detecting when the device return from locked state, then check for new orientation.

Comment: it's not my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If the device orientation is lock; your app will have to abide by it. You won't be able to detect orientation for obvious reasons. So the short answer is you can't.

Comment: in iOS 10+, you can detect the orientation event by using viewWillTransitionToSize even if the user locks outside.

Comment: even, in iOS 9+ on iPhone, you can use viewWillTransitionToSize to detect. However, only on iPad ios 9, it's impossible.