# Allow rotation only for one controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation

I need to lock all controllers from auto rotation except one. It must rotates both portrait and landscape. I have read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8) and tried this solutions

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

but I had no luck, it didnt work. Maybe this is because I use navigation controllers, I saw some mentions of them in previous link but I didnt understand approach because author allowed orientation modes in Xcode preferences and then duplicated them in code.

Maybe some one can help with advice ?

Comment: Have you tried using class func attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation() of UIViewController?

Answer (score 0):

The current method to handle rotation is `viewControllerWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`. Documentation is at this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:

It's a little bit different because you're working with screen sizes not orientations. This is the new way of dealing with sizes and transitions. Think of it like a responsive layout instead of distinct rotation values. To put it a different way, you're not designing for "landscape orientation" anymore, but for a screen thats wider than it is tall. It's a subtle but important difference.

You could implement this method in different ways for different view controllers. If you're using a navigation controller and want to affect child views differently, first I'd say thats terrible UX most likely. But if you still want to do it, you could handle rotation in your Nav Controller.

You should not set the device orientation like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method. Paste this method on the view controller to make the device support portrait and landscape except upside down orientation.

```
func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
}
```

But as chris suggested, you should use `viewControllerWillTransitionToSize` and handle everything regarding the orientations there.

Comment: did you allow the portrait and landscape methods in storyboard setting file ?

Comment: you need to allow them for all the files, then only this  method will work

Comment: I tried allowing all orientations in Xcode and tried deny all but one - neither of these is working with this code