# make one tab of ios tabbar app portrait orientation only

Tags: ios, objective-c, portrait

i have a tabbar ios app. i want to make one of the tabs portrait only. how do i do that? i already tried the solution in [How to force view controller orientation in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8) and didn't help. I put that in view controller's .m code. This view controller has both a UIView and UITableView in it. pl see image below;[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your all viewcontroler write this code:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; //allow rotate landscape, portrait
}
```

and write this code in in which viewconroller you want only portrait.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ 
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown; // portrait only 
}
```

**OR you can use this one:**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass: [CompareViewController class]])
    {
        CompareViewController *compareController = (CompareViewController *) self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;

        if (compareController.isPresented)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
        else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I'm trying out supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow() method. Will accept your answer if it works out.

Comment: Hi..i put the supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow() in my app's AppDelegate.m. I see that this method is getting called but the if() check isn't working in my case. Yes, I replaced the CompareViewController with mine.

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
   NSLog() <== this comes
    if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass: [CInfoViewController class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"xx");  <=== never comes here
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}

Comment: With ios 9 and xcode 7.1, I get this new warning if I compile with above method:

warning: All interface orientations must be supported unless the app requires full screen.

If i build by commenting out supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow(), that warning goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create extension of UITabbarController, and then override below 2 methods in extension:

```
supportedInterfaceOrientations
shouldAutorotate
```

And in both the methods:
just validate, 
`if self.selectedIndex = 'particular index'` (the tab index, which you want portrait) and return accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ankit