# How to lock the orientation of a specific View Controller to Portrait mode?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I hope you are well!

I am working on a Swift 2 app using Xcode FOR iOS 9! and I would like the whole app to rotate on both directions expect a particular view controller that I want to be locked to portrait even when the user rotates. I tried for hours and looked a lot online and nothing worked. Any help?  UPDATE: I tried the two methods below but it doesn't work for iOS 9 :( Please help

Best,
Anas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force view controller orientation in iOS 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8)

Comment: It didn't work for me :(

Comment: Please check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift which help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective C :

```
NSNumber *orientationValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:orientationValue forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Swift :

```
let orientationValue = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(orientationValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

Comment: Thanks, Kemo! But it's not working for me, where do I put the code? I tried this:  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
         shouldAutorotate()
    }

Comment: Just remove shouldAutorotate()  and try                                                               override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { super.viewDidAppear(animated) let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation") }

Comment: This is a poor answer to current syntax for Swift4, no explanation and this doesnt work as @matt.writes.code has pointed out

Answer (score 2):

```
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
 override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return onlyPortarit()
 }

 override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
 }

 func onlyPortarit() -> Bool{
    if(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown){
            return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Manuel's response. Add the following in `viewDidLoad()`

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

This will initialize ViewController in portrait regardless of the device orientation.