# Swift - overriding existing objc method in extension

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

So, I thought I'm quite familiar with Swift, but it turns out, I'm not.

I'm trying to create `UINavigationController` and `UIViewController` extensions and override some methods to simplify control over device rotation.

So, I found that it's still possible in Swift:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220616/982550
But as I don't want to create **base** `UIViewController` class I thought I follow same approach as in Obj-C:

```
extension UINavigationController {

public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return topViewController!.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
}

public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return topViewController!.shouldAutorotate()
}

override public func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return topViewController!.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()

    }
}

extension UIViewController {

public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Portrait
}

public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override public func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .Portrait
    }
}
```

But it doesn't compile with XCode 7.2.1 and Swift 2.1, I got:

> : Method 'supportedInterfaceOrientations()' with
>   Objective-C selector 'supportedInterfaceOrientations' conflicts with
>   previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector

I guess there is no way around it, as both class are subclasses of `UIViewController` I can't make 2 extensions with same methods?

Comment: Why dont you just extend UIViewController, So maybe create a KrodakLayoutViewController: UIViewController. Then add the functions above and use this controller for your views? then each one would have the functionality you require and you just extend it again

Comment: As I stated in my question, I'm looking for the way to solve this one without using subclasses. I already solved this as a problem in the application (using one extension for `UIViewController` and checking if it's instance of `UINavigationController`), but I'm curious about reasons for this error and any ways to 'bypass' it.