# How orientation work in video streaming [Objective-C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming

i use medialibdemos3x in my app & my problem is when i stream video in landscape mode it shows like this Image:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DTqS.png)

& here is my code:

```
@interface ViewControllerPublish () <MPIMediaStreamEvent>{    
MemoryTicker            *memoryTicker;
RTMPClient              *socket;
BroadcastStreamClient   *upstream;

MPVideoResolution       resolution;
AVCaptureVideoOrientation orientation;
UIActivityIndicatorView *netActivity;
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation;}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
//[DebLog setIsActive:YES];
[super viewDidLoad];

[self initNetActivity];


memoryTicker = [[MemoryTicker alloc] initWithResponder:self andMethod:@selector(sizeMemory:)];
memoryTicker.asNumber = YES;

socket = nil;
upstream = nil;}

-(void)doConnect {

resolution = RESOLUTION_CIF;  
#if upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] init:host resolution:resolution];
//upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] initOnlyAudio:hostTextField.text];
//upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] initOnlyVideo:hostTextField.text resolution:resolution];

 #else

if (!socket) {
    socket = [[RTMPClient alloc] init:hostTextField.text];
    if (!socket) {
        [self showAlert:@"Connection has not be created"];
        return;}

    [socket spawnSocketThread];}

upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] initWithClient:socket resolution:resolution];

#endif

upstream.delegate = self;

upstream.videoCodecId = MP_VIDEO_CODEC_H264;

upstream.audioCodecId = MP_AUDIO_CODEC_AAC;
```

& here is my Orientation code:

```
deviceOrientation =
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if ( deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft )
    orientation  = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;

else if ( deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    orientation  = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;

else  orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;

[upstream setVideoOrientation:orientation];

[upstream stream:stream publishType:PUBLISH_LIVE];
//[upstream stream:streamTextField.text orientation:orientation publishType:PUBLISH_RECORD];
//[upstream stream:streamTextField.text orientation:orientation publishType:PUBLISH_APPEND];

btnConnect.title = @"Disconnect";

[netActivity startAnimating];}
```

is there a way to solve this problem?
 thanks

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: @Lion i want Orientation code works in streaming video, it works only on Portrait, landscape view doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per apple guideline, you can't forcefully change application's orientation for different `viewController` when using navigation controller. you can set or allow orientation for particular `viewcontroller` but user have to rotate device.

refer this link for that how to allow different orientations. This have good question and many good answers. [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8)

Hope this will help. :)