# Rotation of uiscreen SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, orientation, info.plist

I have disabled all orientation modes  except the portrait one in my info.plist file because I don't want the app to rotate. However I want one view controller to be only in landscape mode. Can I change the orientation programmatically in the class of the view controller? Or can i disable autorotation in info.plist but enable portrait and landscape mode?

Also I know that I can check the orientation the phone is hold by `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape`

But is there a method that gets executed when you hold your phone differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do present just one VC in an orientation different from the most of the others in the info.plist you must set a set of values that comprehends all the supported orientation.
To avoid the possibility of a VC to rotate in a particular orientation you should override

```
- shouldAutorotate
- supportedInterfaceOrintation
- preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

You will find useful also this answer with a practical example [How to force view controller orientation in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8)

Comment: Is it possible to make an extension of UIViewController and override the method separately for this one view controller?

Comment: If you read the link I've posted, in an answer a user explain how to do that just by overriding a method in the app delegate

Comment: Is it possible to disable autorotation in info.plist?

Comment: But then I can't programmatically switch to landscape when the app is in Portrait

Comment: Correct, if you want to manage multiple orientation, as I already said, you must select all the orientation you want to support in general and for fine grained control use the methods I wrote above.

Comment: How to lock rotation of an avplayer?

Comment: You can't, but you can lock the rotation of the view controller that contains it, by using the methods above.

Comment: Unfortunately the video will also rotate when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

See in UIViewController.h the shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations methods.

Comment: I tried to use the supportedInterfaceOrientations a method but the view did not rotate. Also the should autorotate method does not work when only Portrait is allowed. Or are they only working together?