# how to make youtube video play full screen on landscape using YTPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display youtube video in my iOS application.I m using YTPlayer to display video but when user click the full screen button view should be move to landscape.How to do it.

Comment: how does it behave right now ?

Comment: now its playing in portrait at full screen

Comment: can you link to the library so that we can check out ?

Comment: `https://github.com/sahuamit13/YouTubePlayer`  this example only i m trying .

Comment: Play in landscape is default.. just make sure your device orientation is not locked.

Comment: use this to change orientation http://stackoverflow.com/a/26358192

Comment: my requirement is play video default by portrait and full screen on landscape.how to bring this functionality in YTPlayer...

Comment: already given you the code to do this part ? what is the specific problem ?

Comment: I have tried that code ..but nothing suits my requirement..initially my video has to play in portrait.when click full screen button it has to go for landscape.it has to work like youtube player.

Comment: @Kavithagunasekaran Did u find a solution for this ? if so can u share that, it might help others