# Storyboard loading only once

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

### Explanation

I'm trying to build a simple email code in separate swift files (in this case: `GameViewController.swift` and `MailViewController.swift`).

**What should happen:** I gotta touch the screen in `GameViewController` to call `MailViewController`, and when canceling or sending an email, it shall go back to `GameViewController`.

**What is happening:** It calls `MailViewController` and go back when touching `Cancel` or `Send`, but **only once**. When I try to do it again (even when closing and opening the app again) a black screen shows up when trying to get back to `GameViewController`.

---

### Code

You can download the code below by clicking [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ux2i5vq3e2vs9ls/AAC0tetGruFnKbbCyyby-Jywa?dl=0).

**GameViewController**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set view size.
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)

        //Register mail observer (so I can call from GameScene)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.openMailViewController), name: "openMailViewController", object: nil)
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .Landscape
        } else {
            return .Landscape
        }
    }
}

extension GameViewController{

    func openMailViewController(){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openMailViewController", sender: self)
    }
}
```

**MailViewController**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import MessageUI

class MailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.openMailController()
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .All
        }
    }
}

//Mail
extension MailViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    func openMailController() {

        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self //extremely important to set the mailComposeDelegate property, not the delegate property

        self.presentViewController(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

        //dismiss mail
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        //go back to the game
        backToGameViewController()
    }
}

extension MailViewController{

    func backToGameViewController(){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToGameViewController", sender: self)
    }
}
```

**Main.storyboard**

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: You need to use an unwind segue to go back.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to look for it, but didn't find any code about it. How can I do it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace

`self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToGameViewController", sender: self)`

with

`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

your code will work, but I don't think it's actually what you want to do.

The reason this works is from your game controller you're presenting MailViewController, which is then presenting an MFMailComposeViewController. Since you're presenting two at once, you're getting an odd double animation where a blank view slides up before the mail view slides up. In order to fully dismiss the mail views then, you need to call dismissViewController twice.

A better approach would be to present the MFMailComposeController directly from GameController.

Comment: I tried to do it (as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/mgoVcAL.png)), but it didn't work. A white screen shows up when I, for example, cancel an email.

Comment: Don't remove your previous dismissViewController. You've presented twice, so you need to dismiss twice. http://imgur.com/a/7Yw4H

Comment: It worked!! Buuuuuut its quite slow when dismissing two view controllers. Since I can't present `MFMailComposeController` directly from `GameViewController`, because I need this mail to have different orientations, is there any other way to open only `MFMailComposeController`? I mean, when touching the screen it opens `MFMailComposeController` directly, instead of opening `MailViewController` and then `MFMailComposeController`.

Comment: That's going to be tricky... this post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the reverse segue back in the storyboard from the `MailViewController` to the `GameViewController`.
And in your `MailViewController`, use this function to go back:

```
func backToGameViewController(){
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Change the function to following :

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

        //dismiss mail
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
            //go back to the game
            self.backToGameViewController()
        }

    }
```

Also try this on your device, not on the simulator. Simulator returns an error while trying to open the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

A segue creates a new object, and pushes that on the stack, you would not want to create repeated stacks of objects on top of each other..

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to do it, but it isn't closing `MailViewController`. A white screen shows up when I, for example, cancel an email. You can see it in [this](http://i.imgur.com/mgoVcAL.png) image.

Comment: Call backToGame in the completion of the MailCompose dismiss. Also, try this on a device, not on the simulator. The simulator gives an error while opening the MFMailComposeViewController

Comment: I just did! I worked!! Buuuuuut its quite slow when dismissing two view controllers. Since I can't present `MFMailComposeController` directly from `GameViewController`, because I need this mail to have different orientations, is there any other way to open only `MFMailComposeController`? I mean, when touching the screen it opens `MFMailComposeController` directly, instead of opening `MailViewController` and then `MFMailComposeController`.