# Forcing user to rotate the screen to landscape (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface, ios10

I am trying to develop a video player application. In which when user clicks on the video it will start play in landscape mode. in the situation i am forcing user to rotate the screen. Is this is against iOS UI guidelines. Because of this am i gona face any problem in app review.Please guide me.

Comment: No this is not against of iOS UI guidelines. You can proceed with your define flow.

Comment: Thank You. but youtube and all are working in that manner so i was confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force view controller orientation in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0**

Add this in the viewDidLoad():

```
 let value =  UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
 UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

And,

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```