# Force orientation on view controller

Tags: ios, xcode

in my app i have a navigation controller that shows a view controller forced to portrait orientation. On tap on a button on screen a push is performed and a view controller is shown, and it doesn't have restrictions about orientation, it support all orientations. The problem is that when i tap on back button and i am in landscape, the first view controller is shown in landscape, and not in portrait has expected.
I've implemented all method for orientation, such as supportedInterfaceOrientation for each view controller, but i don't found a way to force the first view controller to portrait.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force view controller orientation in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to force orientation for a particular view by calling the following in the `viewWillAppear` event:

```
// LOCK SCREEN ORIENTATION TO LANDSCAPE
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate setLockLandscape:YES];

// CHECK CURRNET ORIENTATION
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

    // TRANSITION ORIENTATION TO LANDSCAPE
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

}else{

    // SET ORIENTATION TO PORTRAIT
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

    // TRANSITION ORIENTATION TO LANDSCAPE
    value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

}
```

## Transition The View

This will animate the view to a particular orientation, however the orientation will not be locked necessarily:

```
// TRANSITION ORIENTATION TO LANDSCAPE
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

## Lock The Orientation

This will lock the view:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate setLockLandscape:YES];
```

I was able to call `[appDelegate setLockLandscape:YES];` from the property `lockLandscape` I created in my `appDelegates` as well as the following function:

`@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL lockLandscape;`

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
// DELAGATE FUNCTION - LOCK ORIENTATION
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

   // CHECK LOCK LANDSCAPE
   if (self.lockLandscape){

       // LOCK LANDSCAPE
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

   }else{

       // LOCK PORTRAIT
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

   }

} // END - FUNCTION DELAGATE
```

The other code was to fix a bug that occurred when transition from another type of landscape than what I was forcing.

Comment: I've tryed the [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"]; code, but the problem is that the pop animation of the navigation controller looks very bad when the view rotate to the selected orientation, so i was looking for a solution with a better graphic result

Comment: @blackstar26 in my case I removed the navigation before any rotation. Is it possible you could maybe fade it in and out before and after the transition?